# How to add an intro video to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to put an intro video to my website?
I DO NOT want to redirect the user after the video is completed. Instead, what i am looking to do is that when a user visits my site, a video (of 13 seconds)
is to be played upfront..while the website loads in the background. So  that as soon as the video is complete..my website is loaded and the user can browse through it.
Basically, i want a video as a preloader (the spinning wheel shown while some websites load). So, how should i go about this?
Also, my video is of about 3mb..so is it advisable to go for this?? or will it just increase the loading time of my site and annoy users?

please help me..i need some professional advice.
Any inputs would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: leaving aside the poor experience of putting a block in front of your users for 13s before they can access your content you'd want to do as Michael suggests below and have the video on a DIV that covers the content and then when the video 'ended' event fires remove it

Comment: I do not understand why people give down vote for your questions, when I am looking for something similar. It is like they do not like when a "less professional" person asks in a website which is created for "less professional" people to have some knowledge. 
I see that your question is 6 years old. Some rules have changed, especially against us, so I guess that the below answer does not valid anymore. Now, Browsers do not let videos and sounds start at website load without any user interaction, like a click. However I do not want it. Is your question has still actuality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create video element with some id (loader, for example), and set it's CSS to:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 2147483647;
```

When loading is finished, you can remove the element with jQuery:

```
$('video#loader').remove();
```

or with pure JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("loader");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Note that you have to go to parent node, and then remove child of the parent node, you can't just remove the element itself.

Comment: when you say "When loading is finished"..you mean when the video ( of 13 seconds) is finsihed  or when the website is finished loading? Also, using this method will just play my video on the front while the website will be still loading simultaneously (for the 13seconds), right?? i am getting confused..because i read somewhere that Jquery and javascript         are executed first and the html wont be loaded until javascript has completed its execution..so wont that mean that my video will be played first and AFTER that the site will be loaded..instead of being simultaneously??

Comment: I don't know where you find that javascript is running before HTML. HTML is everything, JavaScript in browser can't work without it (because you're loading JS in HTML). JS runs simultaneously with HTML and CSS. If you will remove the video when website loading is finished or when the video ended is up to you. I recommend you the first way - when all files are loaded and JS event DOMContentLoaded is fired. Nobody wants to wait 13 seconds to see your page and most of the users will leave before the video ends. Loading should be there just for notify user that something is happening.

Comment: If you use jQuery you can use `onDocumentLoad`